# Security Exceptions while initializing Nlog event log target

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, nlog, windows-server

I'm using NLog in my ASP.NET application hosted on IIS and Windows server 2003. When I run the code on my develop machine, everything is Okay. But when I deployed the code to the server. The initialization of NLog target will cause an security exception:

Security Exception 
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

```
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [SecurityException: Requested registry
>   access is not allowed.]
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource
>   resource) +51
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String
>   name, Boolean writable) +7462217
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(EventSourceCreationData
>   sourceData) +366
>   NLog.Targets.EventLogTarget.CreateEventSourceIfNeeded()
>   +637    NLog.Targets.EventLogTarget.InitializeTarget()
>   +40    NLog.Targets.Target.Initialize() +264 
>   NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration.InitializeAll()
>   +233

Does anyone when what should I do in order to give the application proper permission? Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got it. Network Service account does not have permission to read/write the event log. That's why the exception thrown.

Comment: For IIS-newbys: How do I give permissions to the event log?

Answer (score 0):

I have run my application once as administrator to create the appropriate rules in the `EventLog`.